# If in parent category

Tags: php

I have this structure

Category > Subcategory > Post

I´m trying to display some content if the user it´s on a specific category, or in it´s subcategory or post.

I´m using this code but it only works if the user is in the category.php, not if the user it´s on a single.php that belongs to the that parent category:

```
    <?php if(is_category('catering')){?>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/canal.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="carta_catering">
                          <p>texto</p>
        </div>
    <?php    }  ?>
```

I tried with if(in_category) but it still didn´t show anything on single.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [`is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) [Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) *checks if a Category archive page is being displayed* - hence it is expected to return `false` on single post pages, whether the post in question is in said category or not.

To check for the latter condition, make use of [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category). If you want the content to show up on category as well as single post pages (in the category), combine the two:

```
if ( is_category( 'catering' ) || has_category( 'catering' ) ) {
     // display something
}
```

Comment: it still doesn´t show anything on the single post :(

Comment: maybe i`m putting wrong the syntax, I don´t know

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( in_category( 'catering' ) && is_single() ) {
```

This will return true on single posts in the category catering but NOT the category archive page.

```
if ( in_category('catering') && is_single() || is_category('catering') ) {
```

This returns true on all single posts in the category catering and the category archive page for catering.

```
if ( in_category('catering') ) {
```

This ALSO returns true on all single posts in the category catering and the category archive page for catering.

Couldn't find anything in the Codex for sub categories.

I would try the sub category i.d with the category conditional tag to see if it returns true for posts in a sub category.